# Response code: 404 while running simple Jmeter Load test

Tags: jmeter, load, http-status-code-404, response

I am new to Jmeter , my manager asked me explore on this tool. Was starting with simple example to put load on website http://202.87.46.83:7001/OESWeb/Login/loginPage.jsp . I have done all necessary setup like proxy etc. While running the same i am getting Response code: 404 error 
Below is http request and its results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), building a JMeter Test Plan manually is a huge overhead in terms of required time.

The fastest and the easiest way to prepare JMeter for recording is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature,

1. Choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` from JMeter's main menu and click "Create" button.
2. Then expand `WorkBench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
3. Configure your browser to use JMeter as a proxy (given JMeter and browser are running on the same machine use `localhost` as proxy host and `8888` as proxy port)
4. Start executing your test scenario in browser - JMeter will capture the requests and convert them into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

Comment: I have chosen BadBoy tool for recording purpose as i am facing issues with jmeter's http test script recorder. But the error is same response code 404 at the same page which i mentioned before.